# setConnection timeout is not working

Tags: java, android

**URL connection code**

```
   URL urlToRequest = new URL(URL);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlToRequest.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization",getB64Auth("admin","admin"));
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
  //  urlConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    String response = readStream(in);
    return response;
```

`setConnectTimeout()` function not working. I need solution, how can set `connection TimeOut`.

Comment: http://thushw.blogspot.hu/2010/10/java-urlconnection-provides-no-fail.html

Comment: Are you catching any exception? Please post the complete code

Comment: Use Retrofit rather.

Comment: This is connection time out due to bad internet or server side issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try read time out.

```
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
```

Are you catching SocketTimeOut and ConnectionTimout exceptions?